# How to manipulate a .NET ASPX form programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to manipulate a .net ASP form on a site that's using AJAX Control Toolkit. The site is only accessible to valid logins, and I do have a valid account. It consists of a search page with a form. Each time a submit button is clicked on the form, the server is updated using the values of some text fields on the form, and then the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION tokens will be updated based on the response from the server, ready for the next request.

I'm using HttpClient in Java to do this. I suspect there's something I'm not doing correctly with regard to interacting with ASPX forms in general.

When I hit the main search page for the first time (cookies are validating my login with the server), I get the HTML for the search page back. I extract the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION tokens for the next request. I've examined the exact form fields and their values that need to be sent to the server in a POST by looking at the Chrome debugger utility after making a request on the site manually. I've replicated them **exactly** as they should be, inserting the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION appropriately.

But the response I get back from the server is not what it should be. What I get back is just the same HTML for the main search page that I get the first time I hit the webpage. The form data I'm using looks like this:

```
ctl00$ScriptManager1:ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$acceptButton
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_ClientState:{"ActiveTabIndex":0,"TabState":[true,true]}
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__LASTFOCUS:
__VIEWSTATE:<token extracted from first page hit>
__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED:
__EVENTVALIDATION:<token extracted from first page hit>
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LabelFee:0
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$RadioButtonList1:Person
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$snameText:aSurname
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$HiddenField1:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$fnameText:aFirstname
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$dayFromTextBox:01
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$monthFromTextBox:January
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$yearFromTextBox:2001
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$dayToTextBox:01
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$monthToTextBox:January
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$yearToTextBox:2008
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$DropDownList1:aCity
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$PropText:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$RefText:
__ASYNCPOST:true
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$acceptButton:Accept
```

I've also tried replicating the headers that the Chrome debugger shows, so my request is including the same Content-Type, Host, Origin, Referer, User-Agent (for my browser) and every other header, including this header `X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true`.

I know there's a lot of moving parts here, but I intentionally haven't mentioned how I'm actually making the POST request with the HttpClient lib because I'd don't want to complicate the question anymore or alienate anyone who doesn't know Java but knows ASP. I'd like to know if there's an ASP issue I'm not addressing, but I can post the Java code is necessary.

**Edit:**
I've checked the debugging info that HttpClient is outputting just before sending the request, and the form data is being added properly as multi-part form data. The headers are all there too.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler (or even Wireshark) to capture the requests sent by a browser vs your app, and then use a diff tool to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got this working. The problem was not specific to ASP in general, it was actually a problem with how Java (specifically HttpClient) was sending the request. I was using HttpClient to compile the request using multi-part form, but after using Fiddler to analyse and compare the requests (see the edited part of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/620227/why-is-wireshark-not-capturing-certain-post-requests) for more details on that) sent from both my application and the actual webpage, my app request was structured very differently.

The real website request had the form options embedded in the request body in what looked like a URL encoded query string. My request was a series of entries in the request body where each option was wrapped in the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers. The requests succeeded after changing the POST to add the parameters like:

```
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramList));
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a long shot, but I've seen weirder things.

You mention this header:

```
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
```

I did some deep googling and found that this is often shown as all lower case in dumps of Ajax and `UpdatePanel` POST requests:

```
x-microsoftajax: Delta=true
```

See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=GkWTN3cVDRQC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=x-microsoftajax%20delta%3Dtrue&source=bl&ots=F2PYXgpJ_x&sig=27UyRkNYH1C-lx4KN74p_UV6V6M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bdPrU8atMoiBygTn0YEo&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=x-microsoftajax%20delta%3Dtrue&f=false) and [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/381_All_About_UpdatePanel_in_AspNet.aspx).

Could it be as simple as not casing the header correctly?